# Anaconda navigator launch erro

Tags: python, crash, windows-10, navigator, anaconda3

I have even tried installing and uninstalling it several times. even after updating every thing and resetting it,it is not starting . no error message is being showed.
anaconda3-2020.02,windows10.

Comment: Can you tell us more about: anaconda version, operating system, specific error messages.

Comment: win10 anaconda3-2020.02, no error is being showed when i try to open it through the anaconda cmd prompt

Comment: And error messages?

Comment: no error is being showed

Comment: when ever i try to open it the green circle appears for sometime and then just disappear .